# Making a JNI wrapper for libcrypto.so functions for Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, wrapper

First i tried using [Cipher Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), but because of performance i have to discard it. The Cipher Class produces a lot of instances and the GC collapse.
The other alternative is to use NDK, so i managed to build [openssl-android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android).
Now with libcrypto.so and libssl.so builded i dont know how to link them with a new .c file in my project to make the wrapper of the ecryption function that i need at Java side.

This is the function of libcrypto.so that i need:

```
void AES_cbc_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
size_t length, const AES_KEY *key,
unsigned char *ivec, const int enc);
```

The wrapper would be something like this:
Java side:

```
public static native byte[] AESEncrypt(byte[] in, byte[] key, byte[] ivec, int enc);
```

Native wrapper (.c file side with shared libraries)

```
jbyteArray Java_com_myApp_Main_AESEncrypt(JNIEnv* env, jobject this, jbyteArray in, jbyteArray key, jbyteArray ivec, jint enc)
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if my english is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

With [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) an interface .java file like this should do the trick:

```
@Platform(include="openssl/aes.h", link="crypto")
public class crypto {
    static { Loader.load(); }
    public static native void AES_cbc_encrypt(@Cast("unsigned char *") byte[] in,
            @Cast("unsigned char *") byte[] out, @Cast("size_t") long length,
            @Cast("const AES_KEY *") byte[] key, @Cast("unsigned char *") byte[] ivec, int enc);
}
```

And we can wrap that into another static method to match your desired API.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, i will read and try JavaCPP and see what happens

Comment: @maxiruani,  it worked? You have any JNI Wrapper working sample?